# A way to bypass SQL BULK INSERT statement access / double hop issue when importing from network shared folder?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

In my environment we aren't allowed to grant access to the network shared folder for the SQL service account.

Thus I created an identical stored procedure that incorporates all BULK INSERT parameters and will use the xp_cmdshell proxy account which can be configured to any user one needs.

Thus the procedure accepts additional 2 more parameters to copy the file first on the local "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\" folder on the server, applies the bulk insert on the file and then deletes it.

I hope this helps, as there is no alternative.

The last 4 parameters provide you the possibility to use the normal BULK INSERT or the one that caches the file on the server %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\ folder, and a few more settings.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_BULK_INSERT] (
    -- main params
    @DESTINATION_TABLE NVARCHAR(250),
    @SOURCE_DATAFILE NVARCHAR(250),
    -- bulk insert params
    @BATCHSIZE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @CHECK_CONSTRAINTS NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @CODEPAGE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @DATAFILETYPE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @DATA_SOURCE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @ERRORFILE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @FIRSTROW NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @FIRE_TRIGGERS NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @KEEPIDENTITY NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @KEEPNULLS NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @LASTROW NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @MAXERRORS NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @ORDER NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @ROWS_PER_BATCH NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @ROWTERMINATOR NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @TABLOCK NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    -- bulk insert - input file format options
    @FORMAT NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @FIELDQUOTE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @FORMATFILE NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @FIELDTERMINATOR NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @MAKE_TEMP_LOCALCOPY BIT = 1,
    @CLEANUP_TEMP BIT = 1,
    @TRUNCATE_FIRST BIT = 0,
    @DEBUG BIT = 0
    ) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @strSQL_Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @importFile NVARCHAR(MAX) = @SOURCE_DATAFILE

IF @DESTINATION_TABLE = '' OR @SOURCE_DATAFILE = ''
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, 'up_BULK_INSERT');  
END

IF @MAKE_TEMP_LOCALCOPY = 1
BEGIN

    DECLARE @tempFolder NVARCHAR(MAX) = '\AppData\Local\Temp\'
    DECLARE @result TABLE (Line NVARCHAR(512))

    IF @DEBUG = 1 PRINT 'Getting profile fullpath: EXEC xp_cmdshell ''ECHO %USERPROFILE%'''
    INSERT INTO @result EXEC xp_cmdshell 'ECHO %USERPROFILE%'

    SET @tempFolder = (select top 1 * from @result where Line is not null) + @tempFolder

    DECLARE @strCMDSHELL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'COPY /Y "' + @SOURCE_DATAFILE + '" "'+@tempFolder+'"'

    IF @DEBUG = 1 PRINT 'Copying the file to local profile temp folder: EXEC xp_cmdshell ''' + @strCMDSHELL + ''''
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @strCMDSHELL,no_output

    SET @importFile = @tempFolder + RIGHT(@SOURCE_DATAFILE, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@SOURCE_DATAFILE)) -1)
END

SET @strSQL_Query = 'BULK INSERT [' + @DESTINATION_TABLE + '] FROM ''' + @importFile  + ''''

IF  @BATCHSIZE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @CHECK_CONSTRAINTS IS NOT NULL OR 
    @CODEPAGE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @DATAFILETYPE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @DATA_SOURCE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @ERRORFILE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @FIRSTROW IS NOT NULL OR 
    @FIRE_TRIGGERS IS NOT NULL OR 
    @FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @KEEPIDENTITY IS NOT NULL OR 
    @KEEPNULLS IS NOT NULL OR 
    @KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH IS NOT NULL OR 
    @LASTROW IS NOT NULL OR 
    @MAXERRORS IS NOT NULL OR 
    @ORDER IS NOT NULL OR 
    @ROWS_PER_BATCH IS NOT NULL OR 
    @ROWTERMINATOR IS NOT NULL OR 
    @TABLOCK IS NOT NULL OR 
    -- bulk insert - input file format options
    @FORMAT IS NOT NULL OR 
    @FIELDQUOTE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @FORMATFILE IS NOT NULL OR 
    @FIELDTERMINATOR IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --start Bulk insert conditions definition
    SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + ' WITH ( '
    -- bulk insert main parameters
    IF @BATCHSIZE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'BATCHSIZE = ' + @BATCHSIZE + ','
    IF @CHECK_CONSTRAINTS IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,'
    IF @CODEPAGE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'CODEPAGE = ''' + @CODEPAGE + ''','
    IF @DATAFILETYPE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'DATAFILETYPE = ''' + @DATAFILETYPE + ''','
    IF @DATA_SOURCE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'DATA_SOURCE = ''' + @DATA_SOURCE + ''','
    IF @ERRORFILE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ERRORFILE = ''' + @ERRORFILE + ''','
    IF @ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = ''' + @ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE + ''','
    IF @FIRSTROW IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FIRSTROW = ' + @FIRSTROW + ','
    IF @FIRE_TRIGGERS IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FIRE_TRIGGERS,'
    IF @FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE = ''' + @FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE + ''','
    IF @KEEPIDENTITY IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'KEEPIDENTITY,'
    IF @KEEPNULLS IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'KEEPNULLS,'
    IF @KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH = ' + @KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH + ','
    IF @LASTROW IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'LASTROW = ' + @LASTROW + ','
    IF @MAXERRORS IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'MAXERRORS = ' + @MAXERRORS + ','
    IF @ORDER IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ORDER ( ' + @ORDER + ' ),'
    IF @ROWS_PER_BATCH IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ROWS_PER_BATCH = ' + @ROWS_PER_BATCH + ','
    IF @TABLOCK IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'TABLOCK,'
    -- bulk insert - input file format options
    IF @FORMAT IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FORMAT = ''' + @FORMAT + ''','
    IF @FIELDQUOTE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FIELDQUOTE = ''' + @FIELDQUOTE + ''','
    IF @FORMATFILE IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FORMATFILE = ''' + @FORMATFILE + ''','
    IF @FIELDTERMINATOR IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @FIELDTERMINATOR + ''','
    IF @ROWTERMINATOR IS NOT NULL SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + @ROWTERMINATOR + ''','
    -- Correct SQL query final character
    IF RIGHT(@strSQL_Query,1) = ',' SET @strSQL_Query = LEFT(@strSQL_Query,LEN(@strSQL_Query)-1)
    -- SQL close syntax
    SET @strSQL_Query = @strSQL_Query + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ')'
END

--TRUNCATE FIRST if specified
IF @TRUNCATE_FIRST = 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strTRUNCSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @DESTINATION_TABLE
    IF @DEBUG = 1 PRINT 'Truncating table specified: ' + @strTRUNCSQL
    exec sp_executesql @strTRUNCSQL
END

IF @DEBUG = 1 PRINT 'Bulk Insert operation: ' + @strSQL_Query
EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL_Query

IF @CLEANUP_TEMP = 1
BEGIN
    SET @strCMDSHELL = 'DEL /F /Q "' + @importFile + '"'
    IF @DEBUG = 1 PRINT 'Clean-up after Bulk Import: EXEC xp_cmdshell ''' + @strCMDSHELL + ''''
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @strCMDSHELL, no_output
END

END
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, Did you find any way/workaround to use proxy account for bulk insert?

Answer (score 0):

put the BULK INSERT into an Sql Agent job that runs on the same server and execute that.

Comment: Unfortunately as per our policy the service account under which the SQL Agent runs is not allowed on any network shared folder. Thanks for suggestion. I tried almost all variants

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL Server agent proxy account with a dedicated AD account.
This is usually allowed by security because this account will have only minimal privileges on SQL Server, like it will be allowed only to insert your table.
You will grant this proxy access to the network drive.

There is a documentation how to create it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks, yes I know this but in this case I can't create a job as it's a stored procedure that's being run by an application on which I don't have access to modify. And the application runs this stored procedure that will trigger the Bulk Insert. I know, it's a pretty strange situation. So, I have had a proxy account created for the xp_cmdshell so that I can copy the file locally first, from which I can import it using the local SQL service account.
I searched a lot for a solution to use a proxy account for the BULK INSERT, and there isn't. Also the filenames imported are specified by the app.